# Gtk Calendar fill whole window

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

Currently I'm writing a GUI program with Gtk3 in Python. I'm placing a Gtk Calendar in my window but my problem is, that the calendar does not fill the whole area.

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.calendar = Gtk.Calendar()
        self.add(self.calendar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = MainWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

If I resize my window I would like to expend the height of the calendar rows so they fill the whole window. The columns resize perfectly but the rows doesn't. Can I change this behavior via CSS or do I have to create a subclass of `Gtk.Calendar`? I also haven't found a method where the cells are drawn (like `paintCell` in Qt) so this is maybe also a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to increase the row height. Sadly, there does not seem to be a row_expand() so to speak. I guess you could always get the height of the window when it is resizing and do some math to calculate the height of the rows...

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.calendar = Gtk.Calendar()
        self.calendar.set_detail_height_rows( 2)
        self.calendar.set_property("show-details",True)
        self.calendar.set_detail_func(self.detail)
        self.add(self.calendar)

    def detail (self, calendar, year, month, date):
        print calendar, year, month, date
        if year == 2017 and date == 24:
            return "SO, thumbs up!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = MainWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

I got this info from https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCalendar.html